# Swift buttons and changing tint color

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a maddening problem. I have a rating control with 4 buttons.

They are each initialised like this in a loop:

```
  var button: UIButton? = nil;
  //.. 
  button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System);
  //..
  imageDefault.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
  mageHighlight.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
  imageProgress.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
  //..
  button!.setImage(imageDefault.Content!, forState: .Normal)
  button!.setImage(imageHighlight.Content!, forState: .Highlighted)
  button!.setImage(imageProgress.Content!, forState: .Selected)
```

The fun starts when one of the buttons it clicked. If e.g. 2nd is clicked the two first should be the same color while the rest look like standard. With 3 buttons, same concept, but another color.

When a click happens I have code like this:

```
  func updateButtonSelectionStates() {
    let idx: Int = self.tag;
    var rating: Int = 3; // whatever
    for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate() {
      button.selected = (index+1) <= Int(rating);
      var color: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor();
      if (index+1) <= Int(rating) {
        switch (rating % 4) {
          case 0: color = UIColor.blueColor();
          case 3: color = UIColor.greenColor();
          case 2: color = UIColor.yellowColor();
          case 1: color = UIColor.redColor();
          default: msNoOp();
        }
      }
      if (button.imageView != nil) {
        button.imageView!.tintColor = color;
      }      
    }
```

Problem is - any button set to "Selected" disappears - no graphic is shown.

It works for most buttons if I explicitly set "selected" = false, but.... This solution does not NOT work for the actual button clicked. It still appears hidden / graphic invisible.

Whatever solution appears, it should also run on iOS7 ...